# How to use FlutterStandardMessageCodec in iOS to write/read binary data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I can read/write binary data using this codec on Android and Flutter side using these classes:

On Flutter side: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html

On Android side: https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/shell/platform/android/io/flutter/plugin/common/StandardMessageCodec.java

But I can't find how to use it on iOS side as standalone class, not in context of Platform Channels.
What I need is just write some data and get binary representation (e.g. NSDictionary -> NSData) and vise versa.

Comment: what you mean by `"not in context of Platform Channels"`?

Comment: @pskink Flutter message codecs usually used in platform channels to encode/decode data to binary and back.
I think it's convenient tool if you need to store some data in binary format and restore it to original form. So I want to use it for that purpose. Not together with platform channels.

Comment: sorry how can you exchange the data between native ios and dart without [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)?

Comment: @pskink I need to exchange this data through socket via my server. I have such requirement for my project.

Comment: seems that you need a custom [BinaryMessenger](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binary_messenger.dart) - the default one is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binding.dart#L144)

Comment: @pskink I don't think so. How can I write NSDictionary to it and get NSData from it?

Comment: for those you have to write you custom [MessageCodec](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MessageCodec-class.html) (i have no experience with `BinaryCodec` so i cannot say if it is useful in that case: *"On Android, messages will be represented using java.nio.ByteBuffer. On iOS, messages will be represented using NSData."*)

Comment: @pskink Why I don't need to write custom stuff in Flutter itself and in Android? 
I can just use StandardMessageCodec and it's doing its job excellent.
This codec also exists in iOS and can do what I need, but how to use it? This is my question.
Looks like Flutter has only header files in iOS and I can't see what's inside.
I looked in the headers, but it's unclear to me how to use it. Interface is quite different from Android and Dart.

Comment: ok sorry `NSDictionary` is supported by `StandardMessageCodec` (i was not aware it is a simple Map) - so you dont need any custom `MessageCodec` for message encoding/decoding, but still you need a `BinaryMessenger` for data flowing over your socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. It's easy!

```objective-c
        // create and fill dictionary with data
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[@"string"] = @"string value";
        dict[@"null"] = [NSNull null];
        dict[@"int"] = @(1);
        // create codec
        FlutterStandardMessageCodec *codec = [FlutterStandardMessageCodec codecWithReaderWriter:[[FlutterStandardReaderWriter alloc] init]];
        // encode to binary
        NSData *binary = [codec encode:dict];
        // decode from binary
        dict = [codec decode:binary];
        // print
        NSLog(@"Decoded value: %@", dict);
```

Output:

```
Decoded value: {
    int = 1;
    null = "<null>";
    string = "string value";
}
```